# How to find out the id of an element using css

Tags: html, css

I need to find out the id of an element on the page using CSS. I know about the # selector for styling things by their id, but I've got an element nested inside another element, and I need CSS to figure out what the id of the container element is. Then it uses the content attribute to do some other stuff related to the id. I hope that makes sense :)

**EDIT**: Sorry I didn't explain it well, I'll try better next time :)
What's happening is I've got a custom `<window>` tag that displays an on-screen window. Then I've got a `<titlebar>` tag that can drag the window around using a javascript function `(onmouseout="dragwin(windowid)")`. I want to make the `<titlebar>` tag automaticly have the `onmouseout` attribute and pass the windowid to javascript. I was trying to make this happen with the :before and :after pseudo classes and the content property (so basicly all CSS)

Comment: Might want to add the markup you are trying to identify.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? Please show some code as well so we know what you're looking at!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the answer is "you can't". It sounds like you want a CSS selector that returns the `id` attribute of one of its children. You'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: You cant find the id of an element using css.

Comment: " I want to make the <titlebar> tag automaticly have the onmouseout attribute and pass the windowid to javascript." - I think you should be investigating [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be unclear but if you want to select child element of another element with known ID you should do this:

```
#someID <children tag>, for example: #myID div{ CSS styling goes here }
```

Comment: This is the reverse of what I need. I need <children tag> to go fist and #someID to go after. This does help me though :)

Answer (score 0):

Not real clear, but I will take a shot:

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class1 > #element
```